# Disable "unlock with voice" notifications Xperia XA1

Tags: lock-screens, privacy, sony-xperia, notification-bar, voice-command

tl:dr - despite repeatedly choosing the "no thanks" option, my phone keeps displaying notifications to setup voice unlock. I Say "no" - as far as I know it is not enabled - but an hour later it asks me again.

How can I disable this feature permanently. (re-asking me to setup voice notifications).

Phone is Sony Xperia XA1 running Android 8.0.0

longer:

Starting yesterday, I got a notification saying "Unlock with your voice" - "Unlock your phone by saying "Ok Google". (screenshots at the bottom of the question)

Now, being a privacy conscious tin-foil hat wearing type - I do not want my phone to *ever* be listening to me for voice commands. No problem, I tap the notification - and another page comes up with a description, and two options: "No Thanks" and "I agree". I choose, "no thanks". The phone seems to be content with my decision. But.... an hour or so later, the notification returns. It's happened about 3 or 4 times now.

Screenshots:

#### Notification

[image: Notification bar with voice unlock notification]

#### No Thanks option page:

[image: Settings page for voice unlock with No Thanks option]

Answer (score -1):

Remove Google Now Launcher (discontinued) from the homescreen and disable Google from Settings > Apps > Apps List.